# What is the order of operations on a Java Initialization block?

Tags: java

I stumbled across a strange quirk in Java today, and I am unable to figure out why this functionality behaves the way it does.

Take the following example:

```
public class InitializerTwo {

    { 
        System.out.println(x);
        x = 100;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    byte x;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        InitializerTwo i2 = new InitializerTwo();
        System.out.println(i2.x);
    }
}
```

As expected the two System.out lines in the initialization block fail because I cannot reference a field before it is defined.

What I cannot figure out is why the assignment (x = 100) *does* compile, and I don't understand why this is not bound by the same definition rules as the System.out lines.  I do know that the type definition is factored in because I will get an expected compilation error if I set x = 1000.

Note that if you move the initialization block after the declaration, the code compiles and yields 0, 100, 100 as expected.

Can anyone explain this behavior?  A link to an official Java spec would be great - I have been unable to find one so far.

Comment: Unless you declare `byte x` _before_ the static block, you cannot do anything with it inside the block _except_ for initialization.  And it appears to be the case that the initialization is applied at the time of declaration and not before.

Answer (score 1):

I think this clears some things up:

> It is not necessary to declare fields at the beginning of the class definition, although this is the most common practice. It is only necessary that they be declared and initialized before they are used.

Link: [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

So what's obvious, because you moved the block Java actually initializes the variable with the default value at first, prints, assigns a real value and prints again. 
This means in the first case the code can't execute because there hasn't been an initial value assigned?

I can't explain the relation the moving the block and the timings though.. So your question is actually still relevant.